# THREE.js custom vr/cardboard effect

Tags: javascript, three.js, google-vr, perspectivecamera

I'm trying to create custom VR panorama viewer using THREE.js.
I've managed to create:

- 2 scenes,
- 2 materials and meshes (different images loaded for left and right eye),
- renderer with scissors (2 perspective cameras).

The result looks like this:
[image]

Everything looks fine for me but I would like to add some kind of "black vr cardboard frame" to both cameras.
I'm not quiet sure how this effect is called, but here is some example:

[image]

Can you please give me some tips?

Comment: What is the reason for not using WebVR and the WebVR-polyfill?

Comment: @Martin Schuhfuß is it possible to set different images for left and right eye in WebVR?

Comment: it is, see here for example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/fdefb19bdd8dbb7d549fa701b1324bfcd9ff1933/examples/webvr_panorama.html#L63-L93 – the trick is to use `mesh.layers` to control which eye will see which mesh.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSchuhfuß I will try to use it tomorrow.

Comment: And if it's really just an 3d-panorama, have a look at this: https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web

Comment: @MartinSchuhfuß I've tried this https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/fdefb19bdd8dbb7d549fa701b1324bfcd9ff1933/examples/webvr_panorama.html#L63-L93 on my Samsung S6 but all I can see is "Your browser does not support WebVR. See webvr.info for assistance." (latest Google Chrome)

Comment: Ah yes, the demos don't include the WebVR-polyfill for browsers that don't support it natively. Do you have a gearVR? Did you try it in the oculus-browser as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That word you are looking for is ["barrel distortion"](http://smus.com/vr-lens-distortion/). You can see a working implementation of this in the WebVR-polyfill [here](https://github.com/googlevr/webvr-polyfill/blob/8063169c6fc52342ebe5524d7f217987f9aa9cab/src/cardboard-distorter.js#L532-L586). Depending on how good you understand raw webgl that might be a bit difficult to read though.

So here are the basic steps of a very versatile approach using two render-passes:

- that split-image you already have is rendered into a framebuffer ([see here](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-render-to-a-texture-in-threejs--cms-25686) for an example) instead of rendering to screen. That framebuffer will be used as a texture in the second renderpass.
- setup another scene and another camera for the second renderpass. The camera should be an orthographic camera ranging from -1 to 1 on the x-axis (something [like this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/fdefb19bdd8dbb7d549fa701b1324bfcd9ff1933/examples/js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js#L32-L37)).
- setup two meshes (based on a `PlaneBufferGeometry`) for the two viewports and assign the UV-coordinates such that the left mesh will use the left half of the framebuffer as its texture and the right mesh will use the right half.
- add the meshes to the second scene-instance, position them next to each other.
- apply the barrel-distortion to the vertices of the meshes. This is essentially what is done in the [code from the WebVRPolyfill](https://github.com/googlevr/webvr-polyfill/blob/8063169c6fc52342ebe5524d7f217987f9aa9cab/src/cardboard-distorter.js#L532-L586).
- render the second Scene to screen